# Бесконечный push в intellij idea

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

Работаю на intellij idea и не могу запушить в гит, пушинг тянется до бесконечности. В чем может быть дело?

Просто бесконечный пушинг в любом случае. Нашел 3 команды, благодаря которым нормально пушится:

```
$ git config --global core.preloadindex true
$ git config --global core.fscache true
$ git config --global gc.auto 256
```

их прописывал в git bash

Comment: Ошибок не выдает? Как себя ведет пуш из консоли, а не из idea?

Comment: @exStas Каким образом пушите в Idea? Что написано когда жмакаете Ctrl + Shift + K?